# Unable to read xml file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, web

I'm loading an xml file with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('status.cfg');
```

The XML file follows the following scheme

```
    <statuses>
    <status>
        <title>Blackboard</title>
        <shorttitle>blackboard</shorttitle>
        <level>1</level>
        <greenstatus>checked</greenstatus>
        <yellowstatus></yellowstatus>
        <redstatus></redstatus>
    </status>

    <status>
        <title>Faculty/Staff Email</title>
        <shorttitle>fsemail</shorttitle>        
        <level>2</level>
        <greenstatus></greenstatus>
        <yellowstatus>checked</yellowstatus>
        <redstatus></redstatus>
    </status>
</statuses>
```

It reads it just fine. But when I create a new xml file with

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
```

And write it with

```
$doc->asXml('status.cfg');
```

It spits the xml file back up like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
        <statuses>
        <status>
            <title>Blackboard</title>
            <shorttitle>blackboard</shorttitle>
            <level>1</level>
            <greenstatus>checked</greenstatus>
            <yellowstatus></yellowstatus>
            <redstatus></redstatus>
        </status>

        <status>
            <title>Faculty/Staff Email</title>
            <shorttitle>fsemail</shorttitle>        
            <level>2</level>
            <greenstatus></greenstatus>
            <yellowstatus>checked</yellowstatus>
            <redstatus></redstatus>
        </status>
    </statuses>
</xml>
```

Which causes my original page to be unable to read it using a command such as

```
$xml->status[0]->shorttitle;
```

However it is able to read it when removing the outer xml tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried declaring your xml like this: `$doc = new SimpleXMLElement();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one case `<statuses>` is root node and in the other case `<xml>` is the root node, with `<statuses>` as the first nested node.  I don't see why you would expect to add another nesting level and be able to read the data the same way.  In your case, when `<xml>` is the root node, you would need to read the data like

```
$xml->statuses->status[0]->shorttitle
```